# Using bfloat16 and tensorflow on a GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

Somehow, when I use bfloat16, tensorflow can't detect my gpu.

Is it possible to use bfloat16 on a gpu? Or I can only use bfloat16 on a tensor processing unit?

Does the error message means tensorflow cannot calculate the gradient?

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: No registered 'Reciprocal' OpKernel for CPU devices compatible with node {{node ConstantFolding/foo/gradients/foo/Mean_1_grad/truediv_recip}} = Reciprocal[T=DT_BFLOAT16, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](foo/gradients/foo/Mean_1_grad/Const_1)
     (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match)
    .  Registered:  device='XLA_GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_COMPLEX64, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]
  device='XLA_CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_COMPLEX64, DT_INT64, DT_HALF]
  device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_COMPLEX64, DT_INT64, DT_HALF]
  device='XLA_GPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_COMPLEX64, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]

     [[{{node ConstantFolding/foo/gradients/foo/Mean_1_grad/truediv_recip}} = Reciprocal[T=DT_BFLOAT16, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](foo/gradients/foo/Mean_1_grad/Const_1)]]
```

Comment: Found it: tensorflow can't use tf.bfloat16 on a gpu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602313/bfloat16-training-in-gpus

Comment: I guess even divide a bfloat16 tensor by a bfloat16 scalar is not implemented. Tensorflow really doesn't support bfloat16 on gpu.